# FreeBSD - run .jar as daemon, service XX status returns 'not running'

Tags: freebsd, java, daemon

I'd like to run a jar as a daemon on FreeBSD 11.0-RELEASE-p8. This is the service file which I have:

```
!/bin/sh

## Service for the camp web site.

# PROVIDE: tabor-web
# REQUIRE: SERVERS mysql-server nginx

#
# Add the following line to /etc/rc.conf to enable camp web site:
# taborweb_enable (bool): Set to "NO" by default.
#           Set to "YES" to enable camp web site.
#

. /etc/rc.subr

name="taborweb"
rcvar=taborweb_enable
pidfile="/var/run/${name}.pid"
logfile="/var/log/${name}.log"
taborweb_chdir="/usr/local/tabor-web"

#command="/usr/local/bin/java" #no, try daemon

command="/usr/sbin/daemon"
start_precmd="${name}_prestart"
procname="java"

load_rc_config $name
: ${taborweb_enable:=no}

taborweb_prestart() {

    # set the daemon / java flags
    rc_flags="-f -p ${pidfile} /usr/local/bin/java -jar ./tabor-web.jar >> ${logfile} 2>&1 ${rc_flags}"

    touch $pidfile
}

taborweb_describe() {
    echo "Service for running a camp web site."
}


run_rc_command "$1"
```

The daemon really creates a PID file at the start with the correct PID, however when I try to run

```
service tabor-web status
```

I got response

```
taborweb is not running.
```

When I check it with

```
# ps -aux | grep java
```

I can see that it is running (and the web service is accessible).

```
 root  2654   0.0  0.2   10428   2132  -  Is   17:12    0:00.00 daemon: /usr/local/bin/java[2655] (daemon)
 root  2655   0.0 17.1 1707364 172744  -  I    17:12    0:20.07 /usr/local/openjdk8-jre/bin/java -jar ./tabor-web.jar
 root  2943   0.0  0.0     404    316  0  R+   17:45    0:00.00 grep java

cat /var/run/taborweb.pid
```

shows

```
2655
```

This is of course not very good for automatic watching - it looks like the website is down even it's up. The good news is that the daemon program runs as should (it restarts the web service if I kill it).

But what am I missing in the script to show correct service status, please?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a simple mistake. The service was looking for the PID file of the java service. But it should have been looking for the PID file of the daemon instead.

```
pidfile_child="/var/run/${name}.pid"
pidfile="/var/run/${name}_daemon.pid"
```

and then

```
rc_flags="-r -P ${pidfile} -p ${pidfile_child} /usr/local/bin/java -jar ./tabor-web.jar >> /var/log/taborweb.log 2>&1 ${rc_flags}"
```

now it works as intended.

Comment: I have a very similar problem https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/custom-rc-d-script-trouble.67196/ I don't suppose you could take a look? I re-worked my rc.d script to a simmilar style to yours, and now I can start the service, but freeBSD doesn't show it as running (when it is)

Comment: Also I believe that "procname" should be changed to "daemon"